# Share with custom content on facebook like Spotifty

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I want to create something like Spotify post when sharing via Spotify App.
Is this possible or only for those who partner with facebook that can create this type of post?

[image]

Comment: Only select Facebook partners can embed HTML5 content to timeline yet. (You can embed a flash or mp4 video though.)

Comment: Well, that sucks, thanks for the answer though